# Pyspark crossjoining

Tags: pyspark, data-science

Let's say, my dataframe has values

```
col1 

|1|

|2|

|3|
```

So I want to create a new pyspark dataframe which have values

```
|1x1|

|1x2|

|1x3|

|2x1|

|2x2|

|2x3|

|3x1|

|3x2|

|3x3|
```

**Can anyone explain me how to make this dataframe?**
I am using crossJoin right now but it's showing error

Comment: Can you post samples of your dataframes and your expected output?

Comment: how can we help if you don't tell what error you receive ?

Comment: Hi. The alias solved the error. So no problem in that. Thanks @Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.range(10)
df.show()
# +---+
# | id|
# +---+
# |  0|
# |  1|
# |  2|
# |  3|
# |  4|
# |  5|
# |  6|
# |  7|
# |  8|
# |  9|
# +---+

df_1 = df.alias("df1")
df_2 = df.alias("df2")
df_cross = df_1.crossJoin(df_2)

df_cross.show()
# +---+---+
# | id| id|
# +---+---+
# |  0|  0|
# |  0|  1|
# |  0|  2|
# |  0|  3|
# |  0|  4|
# |  1|  0|
# |  1|  1|
# |  1|  2|
# |  1|  3|
# |  1|  4|
# |  2|  0|
# |  2|  1|
# |  2|  2|
# |  2|  3|
# |  2|  4|
# |  3|  0|
# |  3|  1|
# |  3|  2|
# |  3|  3|
# |  3|  4|
# +---+---+
# only showing top 20 rows


df_cross = df_cross.withColumn(
    "concat", F.concat_ws("x", F.col("df1.id"), F.col("df2.id"))
)

df_cross.show()
# +---+---+------+
# | id| id|concat|
# +---+---+------+
# |  0|  0|   0x0|
# |  0|  1|   0x1|
# |  0|  2|   0x2|
# |  0|  3|   0x3|
# |  0|  4|   0x4|
# |  1|  0|   1x0|
# |  1|  1|   1x1|
# |  1|  2|   1x2|
# |  1|  3|   1x3|
# |  1|  4|   1x4|
# |  2|  0|   2x0|
# |  2|  1|   2x1|
# |  2|  2|   2x2|
# |  2|  3|   2x3|
# |  2|  4|   2x4|
# |  3|  0|   3x0|
# |  3|  1|   3x1|
# |  3|  2|   3x2|
# |  3|  3|   3x3|
# |  3|  4|   3x4|
# +---+---+------+
# only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: Hi Steven. The above mentioned trick works but what if I am extracting data from some large database. Let's say I have ~1mill row but after perform necessary operations all I am left with 18 rows but applying crossJoin on these 18 rows is showing storage error. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: @DhruvGarg Without [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the details of the error, it is really difficult to help.

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o516.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 56008 tasks (1024.0 MiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MiB)

Comment: Hi Steven. Above comment mentions the error which I am getting. Although row size of my dataframe is just 18(after processing and filtering) and I tried your code and it's working perfectly fine for a new dataframe which have 18 rows.

Comment: The problem is that the code you have mentioned is working perfectly fine for a new dataframe but for the case where I need it, it's showing error. Thanks a lot for the help!